# Signup and login using social plugins, emails and mobile numbers

Tags: javascript, java, user-interface, authentication

I have social plugins for signup, traditional email signup are also implemented. My boss asks me to also allow users to signup using mobile numbers. what are the pros and cons of using mobile numbers for user signup in a website. In both users and developers perspective?

Answer (score 0):

There us no cons if the number is unique and verified. So that no third person makes use of that number to get authenticated.